# Comparing timezone from client with the server one and get client local time if different

Tags: java, timezone, timezone-offset

In my setup I have the server and the client, I have to know if they are in the same timezone (and so it's the same local time).

The client can send to the server the zone Id (like "Europe/Berlin"), the timezone offset from GMT with daylight saving adjustments (int) or the raw offset without daylight saving adjustments (int).

If the timezone are the same so I can assume (correct me if I am wrong) the client localtime is the same as server localtime, else I have to get the client localtime.

I saw there are several classes in java, `ZoneId`, `ZoneOffset` and `TimeZone`, I am a bit confused which one to use.
As for input I was thinking to use the zone id or the offset with daylight saving adjustments.

Thanks for the help

UPDATE: I just want to add that what I mean as server timezone is a reference for me and is not defined as system default. In my case I am considering it as ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"If the timezone are the same so I can assume (correct me if I am wrong) the client localtime is the same as server localtime, else I have to get the client localtime."*, yes. If the clients timezone equals the servers timezone, both local times are identical.

[`TimeZone`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html) is a class used by the old Java classes for handling dates. Don't use it.

[`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) is a class from the new [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package that is much more robust and has a nicer design. It describes a timezone like *"Europe/Berlin"*. This class is used to involve things like daylight saving adjustments in calculation. A `ZoneId` uses a different [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) in calculation depending on winter- and summertime. Thus `ZoneOffset` is the class from the new package to describes specific offsets regardless of other factors, e.g. daylight saving adjustments.

As you are interested in the local time of a timezone, you have to use `ZoneId` here. You can use `ZoneOffset` as well but you will loose the information about the specific timezone because multiple timezones can have the same offset.

Comment: how do I compare timezones with ZoneId?  for example `assert ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome").equals(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")` fails, but this is the same timezone just a different reference.

Comment: @res1 It fails because they *aren't* equal. Two `ZoneId` can have different rules for their zone, thus they *could* have different `ZoneOffset` values depending on other factors. If you want to compare the equality of their *offset* then you need to evaluate that corresponding to a specific time. The rules of an id are represented by a [`ZoneRules`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html) class. You check the offset of a zone corresponding to point in time like `zoneId.getRules().getOffset(instant)` or datetime like `zoneId.getRules().getOffset(localDateTime)`.